# LiveCharts and SkiaSharp throws system type initialisation exception in .NET maui on mac

Tags: .net, skiasharp, livecharts, .net-maui

I am trying to implement live charts in my .net maui project and I follow all the steps as per this website https://lvcharts.com/docs/Maui/2.0.0-beta.330/Overview.Installation but i am getting this error:

System.TypeInitialisationException - the type SkiaSharp.SKObject threw an exception System.DINNotFoundException
[System.TypeInitialisationException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3YSt.png)

Here is my ViewModel:

```
using System;
using LiveChartsCore;
using LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using LiveChartsCore.Defaults;
using LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.Drawing.Geometries;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

namespace TheCuriousCreative2.ViewModels
{

    public class ViewModel
    {
        public ISeries[] Series { get; set; }
            = new ISeries[]
            {
            new LineSeries<double>
            {
                Values = new double[] { 2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 4, 6 },
                Fill = null
            }
            };
    }
}
```

Here is the frontend where I am trying to call it:

```
<ContentPage
      Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TheCuriousCreative2.ViewModels;assembly=TheCuriousCreative2"
             xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.Maui;assembly=LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.Maui"
             xmlns:lvcore="clr-namespace:LiveChartsCore;assembly=LiveChartsCore"
              x:Class="TheCuriousCreative2.Dashboard"
             >

     <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

   <ContentPage.Content>
<HorizontalStackLayout>
 <lvc:CartesianChart
      Series="{Binding Series}">
 </lvc:CartesianChart>
</HorizontalStackLayout>
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

My maui program includes :

```
using SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.Controls.Hosting;
```

and

```
 .UseSkiaSharp(true)
```

Comment: In that exception image there is an `InnerException`. Add to question the complete text of that InnerException. (As copyable text, not as an image.)

Answer (score 0):

I have done a sample by following the steps in the link you provided. And when I used the code in your xaml, it will show nothing without any exception.

And when I changed the  `<HorizontalStackLayout>` to the , the table will show.

In addition, did you miss the `builder.UseSkiaSharp(true)` in the MauiProgram.CS? I just add this following the link. And I tested it on the android and the windows platforms.

Comment: Hi, so I changed the HorizontalStackLayout to a grid and made sure that my Maui.program uses SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.Controls.Hosting; and includes UseSkiaSharp(true) however, I am still getting the error. I am working on mac so I'm not sure if that is causing the exception

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can try to run your project in the vs on the windows. In addition, you can report it to package's owner on the github. The sample I created following the link you provided run well. @isla_just